# Hard edges appear on Material Preview, but mesh Normals and Normal Map fine, no seams or edges

Tags: materials, edges, normals

I'm getting what appear to be either flipped normals or seams on the Normal map, but the mesh seems to be fine, and the normal map appears fine as well. There's only one material on the mesh.  Any thoughts on what to check? (See images)
[image: Problem - pronounced edges -- they look like normal or normal texture issues.]

[image: But the normal map is basically fine.]

[image: And mesh normals are fine (sorry - didn't include the overlay, but I triple checked.]

Comment: maybe add blend file so we can check it out?